# why should you tell on a cheater on a test?

Tags: ethics, cheating

how would you tell on a cheater?

Answer (score 3):

Why?  Because the cheater is going to get an unearned grade, which, ultimately, will devalue *your* diploma.

How? Visit the professor and tell what you saw.  Be prepared to be asked to put it in writing, or to have a meeting with a department chair, dean, or academic conduct committee.